# Does Barovia measure time in weeks or tendays?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, time, curse-of-strahd, ravenloft

Barovia has its own calendar and measures its year in 12 "Moons" lasting a full lunar cycle.

The adventure text in Curse of Strahd mentions weeks. Does this mean the Moons are broken into 4 weeks of 7 days? Do Barovians call these weeks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is entirely a personal DM take on my part, but I tend to treat WOTC's language as literal even in their descriptions. When I ran CoS I took the use of 'week' over 'tenday' to be a deliberate choice, and used weeks of seven days.

Of course, I also rarely referred to a calendar for this campaign. The party is trapped in a demiplane created by the Dark Powers, and the sky is perpetually overcast as per the preferences of its vampiric ruler. The valley is a prison for Strahd and his subjects alike, right down to the economy. Time can have as much or little meaning as you like.

For example, I had the players trapped in a realm that shifted between pitch black nights and twilit days, with the weather frequently a morale-killing cold drizzle or just enough snow to sap your strength. A moonlit night primarily signaled that something wicked this way comes; the only difference is now you - and it - might see each other from further away.

This is a gothic horror setting after all. When the players can't even rely on their sense of time and days and hours blur, the setting rapidly becomes that much more oppressive.

Incidentally, here is one of my favourite pieces on Barovia as a setting - this is the part on the economy specifically (why I called it out earlier), but the whole thing is worth a read: https://www.reddit.com/r/CurseofStrahd/comments/i0u9as/the_economy_of_barovia/

Comment: If it helps, I'm pretty sure Tendays are a Forgotten Realms-specific thing.

Comment: @GMJoe Good point. Barovia is notionally connected, so I imagine you could argue either way. It interacts with Forgotten Realms so it could use Tendays, but it's also its own plane - could just as easily use conventional weeks. Either way, I think the real secret (to me at least) is how little meaning the calendar has in this particular place.